# Powerbuilder rotating text and border

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm trying to rotate my text control inside the datawindow by entering integer inside the escapement expression as shown in the below link.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00844.1200/html/pbug/BABBCCJF.htm

Now the problem is the following: I actually have borders around the text. While the text itself rotates, I also need the border to be rotating as well.

Reason for this is I'm trying to print a label and because the border of the textbox does not rotate, it actually falls outside the allowed width of the paper.

Text control is rotated by 270 degrees.

(BEFORE THE ROTATION:)

[image]

(AFTER THE ROTATION. You can see that the border is not rotated.)

[image]

How do you rotate the border along with the text?

Comment: Thought, this is a bug of PB. Create standalone rectangle with specific coordinates. If course, you ought to calculate them.

Comment: Not sure how your labels are set up, but instead of trying to rotate the text, would it be easier to change the print orientation (landscape vs portrait) ?

Comment: @slapout Only certain texts are rotated so I'm going to have a same problem even if I print it in landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot rotate those. text Escapement does rotate the display but in real page positioning it is still the same. Meaning, if your text is on the most right of the page, you will get two(2) pages instead of one because it will show your escapement properly as vertical, but it will still lapse your current margin. I recommend you use autosize height and use a vertical displayed font. I tried doing that once in my current company but you also have to deploy that font.

I hope I helped somehow.

Comment: Yeah I don't like the idea of deploying the font along with our application but it might be the only alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Use this in your code syntax.

```
dw_1.object.<tag>.font.escapement = ###
```

You can change ### with the grades *10,  Eg:  90º  =  900